# Single Linked List print in order of for loop

Tags: list, loops, for-loop

I'm Trying to print out the linked list in the order I created each node in the linked list. For example it should print out "0 1 2 3 4" but my code is wrong and doesn't print out anything. I think the problem lies somewhere in my for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    struct node *current;
    current = head;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        current = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        current-> data = i;
        current-> next = tail;
        tail = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    current = head;
    while(current)
    {
        printf("i: %d\n", current-> data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appeared to be getting tripped up by the pointer arithmetic when building your list.  Try this instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    struct node *tail = NULL;
    struct node *current;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp-> data = i;
        temp-> next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)            // empty list: assign the head
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            current = head;
        }
        else                         // non-empty list: add new node
        {
            current-> next = temp;
            tail = temp;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    // reset to head of list and print out all data
    current = head;

    while (current)
    {
        printf("i: %d\n", current-> data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finishing it by myself and now understand the basics of pointers. Mine looks slightly different than yours in the fact that my current was being malloced, and my temp was then being set to current, but same basic premise.

Comment: Actually I tried your code, you forgot to set current->next to NULL at the end of the else statement. You need this because otherwise when you print the list in the while loop, it won't know when to stop and will do a weird loop.

Comment: @DanielMartin Actually the next pointer for each new node should be set to `NULL` at the time the node is created.